# Access CSV files using wild card from S3 using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3

Need to access specific CSV files from S3 using Wildcard using Python

Example :ansh-commercial-datalake-prod/dqm/validation-summary/Brand_Validation/*.CSV

ansh-commercial-datalake-prod is bucket Name

```
--This is what I have tried so far

import pandasql
from pandasql import sqldf
import boto
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('s3://ansh-us-commercial-datalake-prod/dqm/
validation-summary/Brand_validation/abc.csv')
print(data.head()) --This is working

but what I need is something like

data = pd.read_csv('s3://ansh-us-commercial-datalake-prod/dqm/
validation-summary/Brand_validation/*.csv')
print(data.head())  --This is not working working
```

Comment: Supposedly awswrangler can do this....

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to resolve a wildcard from within the pandas `read_csv` method (it takes in a [single filepath or URL](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)). What you can do is use boto3 to list all of the CSV files in the bucket then open them one by one then concatenate them into a single dataframe.

**Example**

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

bucket = 'ansh-us-commercial-datalake-prod/dqm/validation-summary/Brand_validation'
conn = S3Connection('<access-key>','<secret-access-key>')
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket)
datal = []
for key in [ x for x in bucket.list() if x.endswith('.csv') ]:
    datal.append(pd.read_csv('s3://{bucket}/{key}'.format(bucket=bucket, key=key.name.encode('utf-8'))))

data = pd.concat(datal)
```